# Have reboot and shutdown show a custom message that needs to be acknowledged

Tags: scripting, reboot

I have a Linux machine that is used in a machine-control context. Operational requirements state that rebooting it is fine, as long as the reboot or shutdown is noted in a dedicated (paper) notebook and a certain procedure on the machine is executed.

I would like to have the `reboot` and `shutdown` commands show a custom message to the user that is executing the command (most likely root), and it would be helpful if that message would force the user to acknowledge it by pressing Enter or another key.

Most documentation on the web focuses on defining such messages to show to other logged-in users and expects the shutdown to be scheduled to some time in the future. I need almost the opposite: The message is supposed to halt root in their tracks and send them to the table with the logbook ;-)

Can this be configured somewhere?

Comment: Is your root user always entering a command or could s/he click on a symbol in a GUI to shut down/reboot?

Comment: @Jens This machine has no GUI, the process will always be initiated in the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function `reboot` and put it in root's shell startup, maybe something along this:

```bash
reboot () {
    echo "Did you enter this in the logbook? Type yes if you did."
    read answer
    case $answer in
        (Yes | YES | yes | Y | y) command reboot "$@" ;;
        (*) echo "Sorry mate, not going to space today.";;
    esac
}
```

Note that this is easy to circumvent (by removing the function, or `command reboot`) so is only good as a first line of defense.

A bit harder but not impossible would be to rename the `reboot` binary and making a script called `reboot` call `the_real_reboot` if the question was answered in the positive. There are, however, issues with this approach if other scripts or programs call/fork `reboot` and are not prepared to answer a question. They may hang or misbehave in interesting ways.

Comment: Nice workaround, thanks for that! I was hoping that there'd be a configuration option for the stock binaries that perhaps the official documentation was missing, but I guess (unless other answers come up) I'll go this way.

Answer (score 0):

How you implement this depends on the interfaces where the shutdown functionality is exposed. If there is no local or remote graphical user interface AND no webmin-like web interface AND this is a physical instance rather than a virtual machine or container then you (probably) only need to worry about ACPI shutdowns, the shutdown, reboot, init, telinit, systemctl power off/reboot commands.

I suggest you do not interfere with the ACPI behaviour. Leave this as a contingency (before pulling the power).

For the others, create aliases or functions for all users (on a system using bash, this should be in the bashrc rather than profile). On most Linux distros the default config is to have a common profile and bashrc in /etc as well as the per-user files in $HOME. In such a scenario, the common file is called from the per-user file so it should be easy to find out if this is already the case or to implement it.

As Jens implies, if a bash function is defined with the same name as an command on the $PATH (or a builtin command) then typing this command at the shell will trigger the function not the command. Prefixing the command with the keyword `command` suppresses this. Note that specifying the full path also runs the stored executable rather the function.

Aliases behave similarly. I don't know which would execute if you have BOTH a function and an alias - but it's trivial to test.

Regarding Jens' code, do be aware that systemctl can be used for lots of other things as well as shutdown, so you'll need to add some additional logic checks. Further, if I were asked to implement this then I would add some logging both for successful and unsuccessful attempts (see `man logger`).